# Properties of iOS messenger

Tags: objective-c, ios, sdk, messenger

I need to build an app such as "Messages" in iPhone, but easier (don't need to send messages to server, only in datebase). I was faced with some questions.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html
In this tutorial messages look like TableView, how can I do them such as in iPhone standard messanger (comics speach). And how can I implement bar with camera button, text box and send button (what class is responsible for this)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck good sir, there is already a class that can fix you up with this and avoid all the work, it's called [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat) (screenshot provided). Or you can even see at Sam Soffle's [SSMessagesViewController](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssmessagesviewcontroller), he is a well known iOS developer who built this class.

It will definitely help you, if you want to mimic that behavior.

[image: AcaniChat]

Comment: Does it mean, that this interface is modified Table View?